# jQuery AJAX listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

If I have object `myApi` with `execute` function

```
var api = new myApi();
api.execute();
```

Inside `execute` I have (*`that` is `myApi` instance)

```
    function execute() {
        $.ajax({
            type: this.getRequestMethod(),
            data: this.getDataParams(),
            complete: function(xmlHttp){
                that.setResult(jQuery.parseJSON(xmlHttp.responseText));
                that.setHttpStatus(xmlHttp.status);
            },
            url: this.getUrl(),
            beforeSend: setHeader
        });
    }
```

How can I make callback/listener so I can do this

```
var api = new myApi();
api.execute();
var result = api.getResult();
var statusCode = api.getStatusCode();
switch(statusCode) {...};
```

if I leave it just this way, these bottom two lines are executed before `ajax` call is finished (`complete` isn't called yet) so I have `undefined` variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it that way, unless you would force the AJAX requests to be syncronous (which probably is a bad idea). You need need to attach somekind of callback method, you can also use some jQuery `Deferred` magic.

Therefore, return the `jqXHR` object which encapsulates a `Deferred`:

```
function execute() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: this.getRequestMethod(),
        data: this.getDataParams(),
        complete: function(xmlHttp){
            that.setResult(jQuery.parseJSON(xmlHttp.responseText));
            that.setHttpStatus(xmlHttp.status);
        },
        url: this.getUrl(),
        beforeSend: setHeader
    });
}
```

and then use it like

```
var api = new myApi();
var req = api.execute();
req.done(function( data ) {

});
req.fail(function( xhr ) {
    var statusCode = xhr.status; // etc.
});
```